# Can Yesod's DB be configured with environment variables?

Tags: haskell, yesod

When I scaffold a new Yesod project and select e.g. PostgreSQL as the database, I get `config/postgresql.yml` that has the connection parameters. But I want to run my DB in one Docker container and the app in another, and link these via environment variables that contain the DB IP, port and whatnot.

How can I tell Yesod to connect to a database by using a bunch of environment variables for configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via the following environment variables:

```
    "PGHOST"
    "PGPORT"
    "PGUSER"
    "PGPASS"
    "PGDATABASE"
```

Comment: Great, thanks, it worked! I still can't get a solid google hit for any of these though which is amazing to me, so which part of the stack does this? Is this a low level db connector thing or what?

Comment: It's controlled in persistent-postgresql itself. I should add a comment on this to the book's chapter on persistent.