# Why does Yesod's TestImport module ignoreEnv in loadAppSettings?

Tags: docker, yesod

I have scaffolded a Yesod app. One of the created files is test/TestImport.hs. It includes the following snippet:

```
withApp :: SpecWith App -> Spec
withApp = before $ do
settings <- loadAppSettings
    ["config/test-settings.yml", "config/settings.yml"]
    []
    ignoreEnv
foundation <- makeFoundation settings
wipeDB foundation
return foundation
```

Why does it have the `ignoreEnv` argument? I.e. why is it appropriate to ignore the environment in test mode?

From the Yesod repository I'm inferring that TestImport.hs is generated from from the hsfiles appropriate to the database used for the app. In my case that's the Postgres one:
https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod-bin/hsfiles/postgres.hsfiles#L9172

The definition of `ignoreEnv` itself is here:
https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod/Yesod/Default/Config2.hs#L147

```
loadAppSettings runTimeFiles compileValues envUsage = do
...
value <-
    case envUsage of
        IgnoreEnv            -> return $ applyEnvValue   False mempty value'
        UseEnv               ->          applyCurrentEnv False        value'
        RequireEnv           ->          applyCurrentEnv True         value'
        UseCustomEnv env     -> return $ applyEnvValue   False env    value'
        RequireCustomEnv env -> return $ applyEnvValue   True  env    value'
```

This question came up because I was having problems running the tests after creating Docker containers for Yesod and Postgres. The DB configuration in config/settings.yml generated by `yesod init` differs from the Docker test DB. Because TestImport.hs ignores the environment, `docker-compose run web yesod test` does not work because it looks for localhost:5432 instead of the Docker IP address and forwarded DB port and cannot connect to the test DB.

It works if I change TestImport.hs to have `useEnv` instead of `ignoreEnv`, but I'm wondering if that's the wrong way to solve it. The question [Can Yesod's DB be configured with environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722740/can-yesods-db-be-configured-with-environment-variables) implies that using environment variables for configuring the DB is appropriate. Is test mode different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concern was that developers environment variables for development would run the test suite and unintentionally use those environment variables, which might cause e.g. their development database to be accidentally wiped. Michael Snoyman discusses this here: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/issues/56

Since two people have run into problems because of this, maybe a different solution is called for, or maybe a comment in the scaffolding about the test environment not using environment variables by default would be helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the github link. It would have helped me if the test runner had printed a message that it was ignoring the environment, and maybe also printed the settings it was using. A clean way to override it would be nicer still, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.